# Convert a hash string to a password like string

Tags: cryptography, passwords, password-encryption

I have a hashed string using SHA1. I would like to convert this string a password like string, meaning about 8 chars with upper, lower characters, and special chars.

Comment: The SHA-1 hash function has an output size of 160 bit. A password of 8 characters has somewhere between 48 and 64 bit entropy. How do you plan to reduce the hash to a "password"? Why do you want to do this? Is this supposed to be reversible? It is necessary to understand what you want to achieve and why in order give some kind of help

Comment: Base64 encode the first 6 SHA1 bytes. But, depending on your usage this may well be horribly insecure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about security / encoding, better ask at the security.SE site.

Comment: this is not suppose to be reversiable

Answer (score 2):

You could use [base-85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) to encode the last 8 bytes of the hash to 10 ASCII characters.

You should be aware that if the character sequence that was originally hashed is predictable (for example, it's a word or phrase, or a commonly used password), it will be very easy to guess from the 10-character string. Even if the original string is randomly generated, finding another string that produces the same truncated hash is relatively easy.

In other words, this technique must not be used for anything that requires security.

Comment: If humans are going to enter the result [Base58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58) is a better solution, the following similar-looking letters are omitted: 0 (zero), O (capital o), I (capital i) and l (lower case L) as well as the non-alphanumeric characters + (plus) and / (slash). Base85 has many more confusing characters to the general computer user such as ., -, :, +, =, ^, !, /, *, ?, &, <, >, (, ), [, ], {, }, @, %, $, #.

Comment: "meaning about 8 chars with upper, lower characters, **and special chars**."

Comment: Quick, "Il", which is capital i and lowercase L? Base85 is not meant for people to enter, Base58 is and is. But then again perhaps the OP is not going to use the characters for human entry.

Comment: Exactly. The OP hasn't given any reason to assume anything about security or user interaction. All we have is an explicit requirement for special characters, with their attendant drawbacks.